# Convert Signed Binary to Decimal, Octal and Hex

Tags: c#

```
     public static void Dec(string[] args)
            {
                string b = "1000000000001010";
                string a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2).ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }

        string B2D(string b)
        {
            string a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2).ToString();
            return a;
        }

        string B2H(string b)
        {
            string a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2).ToString("X");
            return a;
        }

        string B2O(string b)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2);
            string c = Convert.ToString(a, 8);
        return c;
        }
```

I have a signed binary number which is -10 in Decimal form and I want the output string to be -10. My output becomes random and I can't find any solution for this.

Comment: Does `1000000000001010`  mean `-10`? I knew you'd mean `11....110101`.

Comment: It's not a random output, it's just that `ToInt32` is not aware that you mean that first `1` indicates a negative number, rather than a significant digit

Comment: Since you have 16 characters in your string, you need to convert via `ToInt16` in that case, and furthermore the binary encoding of `-10` is `1111111111110110`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a signed binary number which is -10 in Decimal form

1000000000001010(2) isn't -10(10)
The '1' at the beggining means minus sign,
but with negative numbers, you create them in other way than positive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-the-negative-numbers-are-stored-in-memory/

Alex Larionov mentioned in comments, that -10(10) = 1111111111110110(-2) and that it needs to be converted to Int16. It's true, as if 16bit number is converted to 32bit number it becomes positive number:
00000000000000001111111111110110(2) = 65 526(10)
(The conversion fills additional 16bits with zeros and makes number no longer a 16bit negative number)

the 32bit representation in (two's completement) binary system is 11111111111111111111111111110110

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string b = "11111111111111111111111111110110";
        Console.WriteLine(B2D(b));
        Console.WriteLine(B2H(b));
        Console.WriteLine(B2O(b));
    }

    static string B2D(string b)
    {
        string a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2).ToString();
        return a;
    }

    static string B2H(string b)
    {
        string a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2).ToString("X");
        return a;
    }

    static string B2O(string b)
    {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(b, 2);
        string c = Convert.ToString(a, 8);
        return c;
    }
}
```